# Finding sequences in two arrays

Tags: python

Imagine you have two arrays.

```
arrayA = [1,2,4,1,3,9,8]
arrayB = [4,3,2,4,1,3,9,8,9]
```

and there's a sequence of numbers inside of them, if you look at arrayA then you can see that it has "2,4,1" and arrayB has "2,4,1" as well (it also has "3, 9, 8"). I need to write a small script in Python that can find the starting position of the sequence and the length of the matching sequence. Does anyone have any idea how I can do that? The result should look like this:

```
[{start_position: 1, size: 3}, {start_position: 4, size: 3}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
def findUntilNotSame(array1,array2):
    resultPos = 0
    for i in range (len(array1)):
        if(i < len(array2)):
            if(array1[i] != array2[i]):
                break
            resultPos += 1
    return resultPos

# find the length of same value
def findStartSame(array1,array2):
    for i in range(len(array1)):
        if array1[i] in array2:
            return [i,array2.index(array1[i])]

# find the solution one time
def findStartAndLength(array1,array2):

    start = findStartSame(array1,array2)
    start1 = start[0]
    start2 = start[1]
    length = findUntilNotSame(array1[start1:],array2[start2:])
    return [[start1,length],[start2,length]]

def updateAnswer(finalOrigin):
    finalResult=finalOrigin
    for i in range (len(finalResult)):
        if i != 0:
            finalResult[i][0][0] += finalResult[i-1][0][0] + finalResult[i-1][0][1]
            finalResult[i][1][0] += finalResult[i-1][1][0] + finalResult[i-1][1][1]
    return finalResult

def algorithm(array1,array2):
    i, j = 0, 0
    finalResult = []
    while(i<len(array1) or j<len(array2)):
        array1now = array1[i:]
        array2now = array2[j:]
        if(any(item in array1now for item in array2now)):
            result = findStartAndLength(array1now,array2now)
            finalResult.append(result)
            nextStart1 = result[0][0] + result[0][1]
            i += nextStart1
            nextStart2 = result[1][0] + result[1][1]
            j += nextStart2
        else:
            i += 1
            j += 1
    return updateAnswer(finalResult)
```